# Android Studio Emulated device look

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Can someone tell me how to make my emulator look like
a real phone (with rounded borders), cause on my screen it looks like a perfect box.
[image: desired look]

Comment: use real device so that you can experience real

Comment: I know that, but it's kinda practical to have it on the same screen where your code is

Comment: Then you cannot experience like real device rounded border mostly on samsung phone

Comment: Did you use skin for the emulator ?

Comment: You can use galaxy skin emulator Docs Here : https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-emulator-skin/guide.html

Comment: added a pixel phone from AVD manager